# cpp-how to get only the value of c_str()

Tags: c++, string, c-str

I have a function which return `const char*`.
In this function I have the following params:

```
string str;
```

For converting str to `const char*` I use `str.c_str()`.

When I debug I notice that `str.c_str()` contains something (I guess its address) before the value of the string.
For example:
If str="0"
I `str.c_str()` wiil 0x68d5f9 "0".
Why is it?
How can I get only the value of the string?

Comment: You are reading wrong the debugger output. It prints the address pointed by the pointer, then displays the pointed string, "0".

Comment: it's a function, call `str.c_str()`

Comment: @erenon- that exactly what I said. I want to ignore the address pointed by the pointer

Comment: @sara8, pointers _point to addresses_, you can't get rid of this address.

Comment: @ForceBru 38- so what can I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

This *is not* a problem, this is how pointers work.

Pointers point to data contained at *some memory address* and the debugger shows you that this pointer points to address `0x<something>` and the value at this address is `'0'`. Nothing odd here.

When you print this value you got from `str.c_str()`, you'll get an ordinary C string.

```
cout << str.c_str();
```

This will give you the same as `cout << str;`

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't get the address pointed to by the pointer in the string returned by `c_str`. It is a debugger artifact designed to let programmers inspect the address along with the value.

However, returning the result of `c_str` may be undefined behavior if the call is made on a function-scoped string.

For example, this is illegal:

```
const char *illegal_return() {
    string s = "quick brown fox";
    return s.c_str(); // <<== Return of c_str from a local string
}
```

The best fix is to return a `string`. If you would like to return a `char` pointer instead, you need to make a copy:

```
char *legal_return() {
    string s = "quick brown fox";
    const char *ptr = s.c_str();
    size_t len = strlen(ptr);
    char *res = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(res, ptr);
    return res;
}
```

The caller of the above function must call `delete[]` on the result to avoid memory leaks.